# import pandas ImportError: No module named pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to run the following source (I  installed anaconda,
there is no problem with other anaconda libraries ):

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import pandas

def add_full_name(path_to_csv, path_to_new_csv):
    f = pandas.read_csv(path_to_csv)
    print f['nameFirst'], f['nameLast']
    f['nameFull'] = f['nameFirst'] + ' ' + f['nameLast']
    f.to_csv(path_to_new_csv)

add_full_name("./AllstarFull.csv", "./AllstarFullNew.csv")
```

I get

```
"import pandas
 ImportError: No module named pandas"
```

But when I used the command line and did import panda there where no problem

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:36:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

But I still can't use any command of pandas I like to

Comment: can you type 'which python' from a command line and provide an output?

Comment: The Anaconda Python is not installed at `/usr/bin/python`.  That's the Apple-supplied system Python.

Comment: that's was exactly my point

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the same result for running it from interpreter and through "./prog.py", make sure that you have the following in your Python module instead of #!/usr/bin/python:

```
#!<path-to-your-anacaonda-python>
```

The 'which' command that I was writing about will provide the path

Answer (score 0):

Your program specifically asks to run the system Python with the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/python`, so whether you have installed anaconda or not this program won't run using anaconda's Python. Try running the command

```
python program.py
```

(or whatever your program is called). That should ensure that you get the version of Python with Pandas installed in it.

Answer (score 0):

I met this same issue when setting up the anaconda along with ST3, and got it fixed by:
file->preference->browse packages. Then go to user and open Python3.sublime-build, edit the cmd with the python from anaconda. Restart and enjoy.

```
{
 "cmd": ["/Users/*USERNAME*/anaconda/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python" 
}
```